# How to enable Collect signature in Infopath?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-rules

I am trying to access the collect signature in InfoPath form but it is not found on InfoPath designer form. Also the the signature line is not found on the InfoPath form. Some of the tutorial suggesting to add the Digital signatures. But in this case signature line is is not found in controls on InfoPath 2013. Any idea how I can resolve this issues ?

Answer (score 0):

The build-in digital signature control provided by InfoPath only works when using the InfoPath Filler application.

You can change the form type to InfoPath Filler Form though FILE tab->Form Options->Compatibility->select “InfoPath Fill Form” in the Form type section.

Then the Signature Line control shows in the Controls section.

[image]

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

If I follow these steps FILE tab->Form Options->Compatibility->select “InfoPath Fill Form” in the Form type section. The form is not get open in the browser. Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: check the post: How to enable digital signature for browser enabled infopath form https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a19b2f18-781b-4768-8b60-62b13c77b494/how-to-enable-digital-signature-for-browser-enabled-infopath-form?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious